# Запрос в php к таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

в таблице table есть много товаров по цене 300 (столбик price), хочу узнать имя (столбик name) первого товара с такой ценой, пишу:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT name FROM table WHERE price = '300'"));
```

как вообще можно дописать чтоб выбрать первый, или последний товар с таким значением, если строк с параметром  price = '300'

помогите кто знает, заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Поясните, что такое первый, а что последний?

Comment: допустим в таблице много товаров с одной и той же ценой, например price = '300'
как узнать какой товар он покажет написав $result{name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в таблице есть поле `id` или что-то типа уникального идентификатора, используйте сортировку и `limit`:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, 
          "SELECT name FROM table WHERE price = '300' limit 1"));
```

Для последнего:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, 
          "SELECT name FROM table WHERE price = '300' order by id desc limit 1"));
```

Comment: Благодарю все заработало
правда по первой, по твоей аналогии, помогло только вот так:
 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
хотя в таблице  есть id и идет первым столбиком, просто limit 1 не давал изменения, как будто он  по другому столбику выдавал сортировку

Comment: @Леха Автор ответа написал, что надо использувать сортировку, но забыл наверное в запрос добавить. Без сортировки (а limit не сортирует) порядок строк не гарантирован, т.е один и тот же запрос сегодня вернёт одну, а завтра совершенно другую строку.